# I am trying to autopopulate a form's field using a user's previous input. Using AJAX and Django without refreshing the page

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am an amateur Django developer and I'm creating a student's portal as a project. I am having a slight problem as to how a student can select his units based on his previous form field inputs. I have searched everywhere on how to do it, but the closest I've found is an example in W3Schools website[; here it is](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_database). I would like to implement a similar structure in my project but I don't know how to do it in my template. Here are the files

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class UnitReg(models.Model):
    YOS=(
        ('First Year','First Year'),
        ('Second Year','Second Year'),
        ('Third Year','Third Year'),
        ('Fourth Year','Fourth Year')
        )
    SS=(
        ('2017/2018','2017/2018'), 
        ('2018/2019','2018/2019')
        )
    UNITS = (
        ('Algorithms','Algorithms'), 
        ('Artificial Intelligence','Artificial Intelligence'), 
        ('OOP','OOP')
        )
    year_of_study = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=YOS)
    selected_semester = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SS)
    selected_units = models.Charfield(max_length=30, choices=UNITS)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import UnitReg

class UnitRegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = UnitReg
    fields = ['year_of_study', 'selected_semester']
```

views.py
    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
    from .forms import UnitRegForm
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

```
@login_required
def unitregister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UnitRegForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your unit registration was successful')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UnitRegForm()
    context = {
        'form':form
        }
    return render(request, 'unitreg.html', context)
```

unitreg.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <form method="POST">
                {%csrf_token%}
                {{form|crispy}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content%}
```

Comment: a) W3Schools is absolute poop and b) you haven't implemented any JQuery code at all from what you've posted.

Comment: yes, I haven't added any jQuery since I'm having a problem writing it plus the AJAX script for fetching the said data. (P.S: I forgot to add more units in the model for the students selection)

Comment: Well no-one here is going to write your code for you. What "problem" are you having writing it? You need to at least tell us where your issue is, and show us what you tried.